# How to define MonadBaseControl for a monad that is NOT a transformer?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Related to [MonadTransControl instance for a custom monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653666/monadtranscontrol-instance-for-a-custom-monad) where, unfortunately (but understandably) the author gave up on `monad-control`. However, that is not an option for me, because I need to use `Control.Concurrent.Async.Lifted` within my custom monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data FeatureFlag = Feature1 | Feature2

newtype AppM (features :: [FeatureFlag]) a = AppM (ReaderT Env IO a) 
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO, MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask, MonadUnliftIO)
```

I've tried reading https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/monad-control-1.0.2.3/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html but nothing seems to be making sense to me. *Conceptually* I understand why `MonadBaseControl` and friends are required, thanks to the walk-through at https://www.yesodweb.com/book/monad-control , but I can't figure out how to *implement* this.

The official docs have an implementation guide at the very top, but it assumes monad-transformers:

> Define instances MonadTransControl T for all transformers T, using the defaultLiftWith and defaultRestoreT functions on the constructor and deconstructor of T.
>
> [...]
>
> Define instances MonadBaseControl B m => MonadBaseControl B (T m) for all transformers:

**How do I write a sensible instance for `MonadBaseControl IO (AppM fs)` where the `fs` part is preserved when the monad is unwrapped and wrapped again?** Also, I'm assuming that I don't really have to implement `MonadTransControl`, because `AppM fs` is not a transformer.

PS: Also related - [Is it safe to derive MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadBaseControl, MonadUnliftIO, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863771/is-it-safe-to-derive-monadthrow-monadcatch-monadbasecontrol-monadunliftio-et)

Comment: What goes wrong if you just cargo-cult `ReaderT`'s instance?

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppM` is basically a `ReaderT` transformer; you've just specialized it to `IO`.  You could rewrite it as:

```
newtype AppT (features :: [FeatureFlag]) m a = AppT (ReaderT Env m a)
```

with a type alias for the IO version:

```
type AppM features = AppT features IO
```

Then you should be able to use a combination of usual deriving clauses and standalone deriving clauses to get the classes you want.

At least, the following typechecks, and GHC seems to think it's produced an `instance MonadBaseControl IO (AppT features IO)`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, GADTs, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
    KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses, ScopedTypeVariables, StandaloneDeriving,
    UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Catch
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.IO.Unlift
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control

data FeatureFlag = Feature1 | Feature2

data Env

newtype AppT (features :: [FeatureFlag]) m a = AppT (ReaderT Env m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader Env, MonadIO,
            MonadThrow, MonadCatch, MonadMask,
            MonadTrans, MonadTransControl)
type AppM features = AppT features IO
deriving instance MonadBase IO (AppM features)
deriving instance MonadBaseControl IO (AppM features)
deriving instance MonadUnliftIO (AppM features)
```

Comment: So it occurs to me that it might be nice for the unlift instance to tag its state with the features to prevent one from writing `AppT fs m a -> AppT fs' m a` via unlifting. Perhaps that is what the original question asker is after?